How to automatically rebuild a package with a patch after an update?
I use several of my patches for packages from the Ubuntu repository.
Every time a new version comes out, I have to patch the new package and run the build commands manually.
Is there a tool that will allow me to put a patch in /apt/patch/network-manager/10-remove-netplan.diff and when updating the network-manager package in the repository, automatically rebuild it with my patch?
I read the 2017 thread, maybe something has changed, or do you have better solutions?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404213/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-maintain-local-patches-to-debian-packages
+++ Thu Aug 15 19:38:52 UTC 2024
Is it possible to automate the build+update via launchpad?

Pin the packages so that they are not updated anymore. Then your patches will not be overwritten.

@ArchismanPanigrahi, This is a good solution for packets that do not interact with the network. However, I would like to apply patches to applications that interact with the network, and browsers.

If the patches are generic, can you upstream them?

Nothing has changed since the 2017 thread. However, NetworkManager now reads netplan YAML in recent releases of Ubuntu if that helps.
